# Swift - Convert a binary string to its ascii values

Tags: swift

I have a string of binary values e.g. "010010000110010101111001". Is there a simple way to convert this string into its ascii representation to get (in this case) "Hey"?

Only found the other way or things for Integer:

```
    let binary = "11001"
    if let number = Int(binary, radix: 2) {
        print(number) // Output: 25
    }
```

Do someone know a good and **efficient** solution for this case?

Comment: I think your solution is simple too.

Comment: thats not my solution, I need one o get ascii values not ints

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may need to split the input binary digits into 8-bit chunks, and then convert each chunk to an ASCII character. I cannot think of a super simple way:

```
var binaryBits = "010010000110010101111001"

var index = binaryBits.startIndex
var result: String = ""
for _ in 0..<binaryBits.characters.count/8 {
    let nextIndex = binaryBits.index(index, offsetBy: 8)
    let charBits = binaryBits[index..<nextIndex]
    result += String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(charBits, radix: 2)!))
    index = nextIndex
}
print(result) //->Hey
```

Comment: Can you help with reversing this?

Comment: @rv7284, Better start a new thread of your own. It may be a little bigger code than to write as a comment.

Answer (score 7):

A variant of [@OOPer's solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42668337/2976878) would be to use a conditionally binding `while` loop and [`index(_:offsetBy:limitedBy:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/collection/1787606-index) in order to iterate over the 8 character substrings, taking advantage of the fact that `index(_:offsetBy:limitedBy:)` returns `nil` when you try to advance past the limit.

```
let binaryBits = "010010000110010101111001"

var result = ""
var index = binaryBits.startIndex

while let next = binaryBits.index(index, offsetBy: 8, limitedBy: binaryBits.endIndex) {
    let asciiCode = UInt8(binaryBits[index..<next], radix: 2)!
    result.append(Character(UnicodeScalar(asciiCode)))
    index = next
}

print(result) // Hey
```

Note that we're going via `Character` rather than `String` in the intermediate step – this is simply to take advantage of the fact that `Character` [is specially optimised](https://github.com/apple/swift/blob/master/stdlib/public/core/Character.swift#L67) for cases where the UTF-8 representation fits into 63 bytes, which is the case here. This saves heap-allocating an intermediate buffer for each character.

---

Purely for the fun of it, another approach could be to use [`sequence(state:next:)`](https://developer.apple.com/reference/swift/2011998-sequence) in order to create a sequence of the start and end indices of each substring, and then `reduce` in order to concatenate the resultant characters together into a string:

```
let binaryBits = "010010000110010101111001"

// returns a lazily evaluated sequence of the start and end indices for each substring
// of 8 characters.
let indices = sequence(state: binaryBits.startIndex, next: {
    index -> (index: String.Index, nextIndex: String.Index)? in

    let previousIndex = index

    // Advance the current index – if it didn't go past the limit, then return the
    // current index along with the advanced index as a new element of the sequence.
    return binaryBits.characters.formIndex(&index, offsetBy: 8, limitedBy: binaryBits.endIndex) ? (previousIndex, index) : nil
})

// iterate over the indices, concatenating the resultant characters together.
let result = indices.reduce("") {
    $0 + String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(binaryBits[$1.index..<$1.nextIndex], radix: 2)!))
}

print(result) // Hey
```

On the face of it, this appears to be much less efficient than the first solution (due to the fact that `reduce` should copy the string at each iteration) – however it appears the compiler is able to perform some optimisations to make it not much slower than the first solution.

Comment: I'm a real fan of `sequence(state:next)`, even though it usually tend to suffer w.r.t. performance when compared to more "classic" approaches. Incidentally, my vote (or a yet-to-be-updated shortly previous one) on this good answer should push you over 999 Swift tag upvotes. So grats somewhat in advance on the gold badge! :D

Comment: @dfri Yeah, I would definitely use it more often if it's performance wasn't an issue and it's syntax was a little less daunting, I usually always prefer the more "classical" approaches :) And thanks for the +1 :D Unfortunately you missed the 1000th upvote by a minute or two! You got the 1001th upvote ;) Looking forward to wielding the mighty mjölnir :)

Comment: Yeah, me too :) darn, the 1000th would have been neat! Heh yes my deleted comment had some confusion w.r.t. the fact that only the silver badge was shown at your profile, but I guess the gold one will soon appear there as well :) The first hammer strike will hopefully give much satisfaction!

Answer (score 1):

Does basically the same as OOPer's solution, but he/she was faster and has a shorter, more elegant approach :-)

```
func getASCIIString(from binaryString: String) -> String? {

    guard binaryString.characters.count % 8 == 0 else {
        return nil
    }

    var asciiCharacters = [String]()
    var asciiString = ""

    let startIndex = binaryString.startIndex
    var currentLowerIndex = startIndex

    while currentLowerIndex < binaryString.endIndex {

        let currentUpperIndex = binaryString.index(currentLowerIndex, offsetBy: 8)
        let character = binaryString.substring(with: Range(uncheckedBounds: (lower: currentLowerIndex, upper: currentUpperIndex)))
        asciiCharacters.append(character)
        currentLowerIndex = currentUpperIndex
    }

    for asciiChar in asciiCharacters {
        if let number = UInt8(asciiChar, radix: 2) {
            let character = String(describing: UnicodeScalar(number))
            asciiString.append(character)
        } else {
            return nil
        }
    }

    return asciiString
}

let binaryString = "010010000110010101111001"

if let asciiString = getASCIIString(from: binaryString) {
    print(asciiString) // Hey
}
```

Answer (score 1):

A different approach

```
let bytes_string: String = "010010000110010101111001"
var range_count: Int = 0

let characters_array: [String] = Array(bytes_string.characters).map({ String($0)})

var conversion: String = ""

repeat
{
    let sub_range = characters_array[range_count ..< (range_count + 8)]
    let sub_string: String = sub_range.reduce("") { $0 + $1 }

    let character: String = String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8(sub_string, radix: 2)!))

    conversion += character

    range_count += 8

} while range_count < characters_array.count

print(conversion)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this:

```swift
extension String {
    var binaryToAscii: String {
        stride(from: 0, through: count - 1, by: 8)
        .map { i in map { String($0)}[i..<(i + 8)].joined() }
        .map { String(UnicodeScalar(UInt8($0, radix: 2)!)) }
        .joined()
    }
}
```